# What is the best way to use Tasks to iteratively exhaust a REST endpoint?

Tags: airflow

Hello I believe what we are trying to do must be quite a common requirement, but basically we have a REST endpoint which we must continuously page through to retrieve the latest data.

e.g.

`GET /api/search?page=1`

...process results...

`GET /api/search?page=2`

...process results...

`GET /api/search?page=3`

...no results, keep polling until there are results...

What would be a good way to design a task to do this? Do we just have to have a DAG that continuously attempts these endpoints using a page number vaiable?

Reading through the documentation I understand long running DAGs should be avoided as well as variables, but perhaps there is no alternative?

Comment: You can use the Httpsensor operator for this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/operators.html#howto-operator-httpsensor

Comment: or [PythonSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/python/index.html#airflow.sensors.python.PythonSensor)